# php search accepting incomplete entered input

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo, preg-match

I created a very basic and simple search programming that displays the first and last name of the entered username in a fetched row. It was successful, but only if the entered username matches the exact characters and length of the username in the database. I want my code to read it even if it isn't complete; for example, the username in the database is "baymax16", and the entered username is "max16", I want it to return true since some characters matches. I used `preg_match()`, but there's an error. Should I use `preg_match()`? If yes, how should I use it correctly? If no, what should I use?

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=sample;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM search WHERE username=:username");
    $query->execute(['username' => $search]);

    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if(count($row)) {
        if(preg_match($search, $row)) {
            echo $row->firstname . ' ' . $row->lastname;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query there:
`SELECT * FROM search WHERE username=:username` is telling the database to extract the data IFF the supplied string is EQUAL to the string that exists in the database.

Why not use `LIKE` operator in the query?

`SELECT * FROM search WHERE username LIKE CONCAT('%', :username,'%');`

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy